# Can't migrate accurately from RxJava2 to RxJava3

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-kotlin, rx-binding, rx-java3

I can't convert this method to RxJava3 despite having upgraded the dependencies

```
fun setSearchField(searchField: EditText) {
        searchDisposable = searchField.afterTextChangeEvents()
            .skipInitialValue()
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map { it.editable()?.toString() ?: "" }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(::onSearchQueryUpdated)
    }
```

Type mismatch.
Required:
io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable?
Found:
io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable!

```
    def retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.4"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding:3.1.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava3-retrofit-adapter:3.0.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2"
```

How should I accurately clean  the project from RxJava2?

I tried Invalidate caches/Restart: nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: Examine the dependency graph, maybe there is a library or module that still has rx2 as transitive dependency. You can print this graph in the terminal with `./gradlew :app:dependencies`, or show them in the IDE (project structure).

Comment: Nope, the command fails, and the IDE doesn't show any of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependencies: ./gradlew :dependencies

```
implementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.4
|    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0
|    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0 -> 3.0.4 (*)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0
|    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0 -> 3.0.4 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding:3.1.0
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 FAILED
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41 -> 1.3.71
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.71
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10
|    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.3
|    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1
|         \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6 -> 2.2.10 (*)
```

You see, that rxbinding3 has a transitive dependency to

```
|    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10
```

Which overwrites RxJava3

## Solution:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding4:rxbinding:4.0.0'
```